# Biztalk send port cannot find certificate

Tags: wcf, security, biztalk

Good afternoon,
I'm getting the following error trying to use a BizTalk send port to talk to a web service:

```
"System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot find the X.509 certificate using the following search criteria: StoreName 'My', StoreLocation 'CurrentUser', FindType 'FindByThumbprint'
```

The send port is configured as type 'WCF-WShttp', 'Transport' security mode, 'Certificate' credential type.

I have a self signed certificate that has the same thumbprint value as shown in the bizTalk configuration dialog. I've checked the file shows the correct thumbprint and it is not expired.

- I've tried installing it in the all the following stores:
  "Current User": Personal, Trusted Publishers, Trusted People, Trusted CA's 
  "Local Computer": Personal, Trusted Publishers, Trusted People, Trusted CA's.
- When I go to the wcf send port configuration in the BizTalk management console it allows me to browse available certs. Our cert appears and lets me select it.
- I made sure the service account for biztalk is added to the cert permissions.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The client certificate needs to be installed in BizTalk host user account certificate "Personal Store", also make sure any root certificate (if any) is in trusted store and then set it on adapter configuration.

Comment: I used MMC, added a snap in for the service account, picked "BiztalkServerApplication" (that's the only host instance it allows me to choose), then added it to every store that seemed appropriate. I went to the send port security tab and reselected the cert. Still get the same thing :(

Comment: I notice the biztalk management console allows you to pick certs from the personal store of the current user, but the biztalk service account will get the certs from it's personal store. That seems like a bug to me. You can't pick from the cert list it actually uses.

Comment: If u r testing locally then try use host account as yr account and then add certificate to yr personal  store and then change send port configure and test. Alternatively you should login with user you have host running under and then configure it.

Answer (score 1):

Following these procedures should work. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg634534(v=bts.70).aspx. Probably the most important thing to note is that you must be logged on to the server with the actual account that is running the adapter handler's host instance service. And for a self-signed certificate I think you just need to add it to the Trusted Root CAs for that account too.

Comment: installed the .cer file in the personal store for Local Computer and Current user, while logged in to the biztalk service account. I pulled up internet explorer and navigated to the web service svc page. I get an error page "There is a problem with this website's security certificate." I tried clicking the 'continue to this website' link and I get a 403 forbidden error. I think I have multiple issues but shouldn't I at least not get a 'problem with this certificate' error?

Answer (score 1):

Did you copy the thumbprint directly from the mmc to your BizTalk Send Port.
First try to copy it to notepad++ and check if you see any special characters.

If that's the case remove the special characters and then copy that thumbprint to your BizTalk Send Port.

Comment: You can use wcf-custom or wcf-wshttp port types in the wcf-wshttp type you don't enter the thumbprint string, you select from a list of certs and it enters it. I can't see to get that to work so I'm trying the wcf-custom version now. I'll be sure to be careful about that. Thanks